# Passing partial view data to controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

Let say I have a model DailyTasks and a model Task. The initial view is strongly typed with DailyTasks model. It shows a list of existing tasks for the day. Users can add more task to the list/table by clicking the add button. When the add button is clicked, I render a partial view which is tied to a Task model.

I want to be able to save any changes the user made to the existing tasks and as well as newly added tasks.

I'm not sure sure what is the best way to do this. I have been playing with model binding and as well as creating a json object of the model and then pass it to the controller upon Save. So far I was only able to pass back the existing tasks to the Save controller, none of the newly added tasks show up.

Model:

```
public class DailyTasks
{  
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public List<Task> TaskList{ get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string MyTask { get; set; }
}
```

Main View:

```
@model Example.Models.DailyTasks

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "DailyTasks", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
<input type="button" value="Add New Task" id="addBtn" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="saveBtn"/>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Column Header Name Goes Here</th>
        <th>Column Header Name Goes Here</th>
    </tr>

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.TaskList.Count(); i++)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.TaskList[i].ID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.TaskList[i].ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.TaskList[i].MyTask)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.TaskList[i].MyTask)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addBtn").on("click", function () {
        $.get('@Url.Action("AddTask")', function (data) {
            $("table tbody").append(data);
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

Add New Task AcitionResult for Partial View:

```
public ActionResult AddTask()
    {
        Task model = new Task();
        return PartialView("_AddTask", model);
    }
```

Partial View (_AddTask):

```
    @model Example.Models.Task

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.MyTask)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.MyTask)
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: can you provide the code from you controllers/view? its difficult to make "best way" suggestions based only on a model.

Comment: Look at this link http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/ and especially part of non sequentiel indexes.

Comment: I have provided the code. Sorry it's a little lengthy. The concept is simple though. I'm just trying to add new item to the list by rendering a partial view and add it to the table on the main view. The only trouble I am struggling with here is that upon Submit, it only sends back the original Tasks list and none of the newly added tasks (aka partial view items) are posted back. I check chrome debug tool to make sure it got appended properly and it's there. Let me know if you need a screenshot of the debug tool. Thanks in advance for looking into this guys.

Comment: Perhaps my approach is wrong??? I'm open for better suggestions to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Note: I have also tried Json route by creating a json obj and push each new item to the list, then stringify it and post it back to the controller. I run into the same problem.... it works without the newly added task... Let me know if anyone is interested in the json code as well. I was able to get it to work with the traditional bindings (Request and FormCollection), I  would prefer model binding or json method which is a lot cleaner. I also very much interested find out why my attempt with json/model binding didn't work. I'm hoping some expert can give me a better insight. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found exactly what I needed here: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/ Now I can use modelbinding method instead of the traditional ways (FormCollection and Request).

I hope it helps someone in the future. Also, thanks to Tobias for the link. It is definitely discusses core problem that i presented but unfortunately the solution found there didn't work in my case.

Cheers!